# How to globalize RegularExpressionValidator Error Message?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox, validation

Is there any way where we can globalize RegularExpressionValidator errorMessage? and instead of calling the error message from  we can call it off a resource file ?
Here is what I have:

```
<FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="addCREDIT_TYPE" style="WIDTH: 55px" Runat="Server" MaxLength="1"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valCreditType" ControlToValidate="addCREDIT_TYPE" ValidationExpression="B|P|C|b|p|c"
                                    ErrorMessage="Invalid Type. Enter B or C or P" Runat="server" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                    </FooterTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me. Just in case if someone gets stuck in same position heres the answer. It was pretty simple.

ErrorMessage="<%# Resources.MyProject.CustomErrorMessage %>"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply render error message not with static text but with dynamic value from resources. 
Article [esources and Localization in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx) covers some possibilities:

```
... ErrorMessage="Text="<%$ Resources:Litware, ErrorMessage %>" ...
```

Comment: I tried that and it didnt work for me. no error message was displayed.                                                                 'asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valCreditType" ControlToValidate="addCREDIT_TYPE" ValidationExpression="B|P|C|b|p|c"
          ErrorMessage="<%Resources.MACS.creditcode, ErrorMessage %>"  Runat="server" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator> '